# LaunchAgent - Is there something like RunAtScreenSaver?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, screensaver, launchd, launchdagent

I am looking for a way to execute my app (it's a background task) at times, where the machine is "idle". A good incident would be when the screensaver launches. I already read the manual auf launchd and already use a LaunchAgent to lauch my app at certain intervals, but I found nothing that might help me launching my app when the screensaver is active.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Josh

Answer (score 2):

Have another process that runs in the background and listens for distributed notifications named `com.apple.screenIsLocked` and `com.apple.screenIsUnlocked`. (That's for Snow Leopard. Leopard used different notification names. Use [Notification Watcher](http://tildesoft.com/Programs.html) and experimentation to find out what they are.) When one of those notifications comes in, launch or nicely-quit* your real app, as appropriate.

*You'll want to use an Apple Event for this.

Comment: These notifications aren't available in Snow Leopard anymore. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

For Snow Leopard the screenIsLocked and screenIsUnlocked notifications aren't available anymore. What I've used successfully are these:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(locked:) name:NSWorkspaceScreensDidSleepNotification object:nil];

[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(unlocked:) name:NSWorkspaceScreensDidWakeNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Are these sent around the screensaver, or only display hardware sleep?

Comment: To be frank I never ever use screen savers. Quite frankly I don't understand why anyone would anymore since we've stopped using CRTs! Any screen saver that is not 100% white can only damage the screen or do nothing. So I don't know nor do I care for my use case :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a new user, so I can't comment on or vote up portenkirchner's suggestion.  Matt Swann has moved his [ScriptSaver](http://swannman.github.io/scriptsaver/).

It does exactly what I want, run an AppleScript program when I unlock the screensaver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ScriptSaver by Matt Swann. This is a Mac OS X screensaver which can run AppleScripts when it activates and deactivates.

http://swannman.wordpress.com/projects/scriptsaver/